# Based on user inputs add multiple dynamic lines through python script

Tags: python

suppose below is a sample of an xml file.

```
<AVP code="123" name="abcd">
<type>
    <high/>
</type>
</AVP>
<AVP code="234" name="ukbkj">
<type>
    <enum/>
</type>
<enum name="erdf"/>
<enum name="asdc"/>
 .....
 .....
(here we can add many enum name 2 4 7 9 whatever)
</AVP>
<State>
</State>
```

In this xml file I have to add AVPs with all its attributes(see above code from "AVP tag" to "/AVP tag"). But addition should done before State tag. Also we have to check that if avp type is "enum/" tag, then we have add "enum name" tag after "/Type" tag, that can be any number, that i can achieved with "while loop" but if it not "enum/" tag then nothing will be added after "/Type" tag.

example i want to add 2 avps one with code = 909, name = earth, type = high.
another one with code = 169, name = universe, type = enum(when enum comes) then user add to be asked for enum name, that should be done in loop and at last it should be break so that control can come out. And input should be added in xml file.
What I trying to do is in while loop:
Asking the user to enter choice like 1 to insert AVP 2 to delete and 3 to exit:
if user enter 1 then give avp code, its name, type etc.
if he insert 2 then delete AVP(I dont want u all to answer this please ignore delete operation)
if he insert then it will exit by using break

Comment: What is precisely your question? You want to do several things, which ones are a problem to you, what have you tried already?

Comment: Don't attempt to implement everything at once. Implement updating the XML. Implement user input. Implement looping. Ask a question about one of those things, if you are having difficulty.

Comment: @FrancisColas My question is to add multiple lines based on user input. please Understand It.... and don't downvote my question.

Comment: @PeterWood Hey, I am not implementing many things. I am just inserting lines based on user input. Please understand it... If you r not able to understand then U can leave without any hint.. but don't downvote my question.

Comment: You should indeed split your problem, try things out on your own, and when you get stuck somewhere, ask here. We'd love to help you out. Currently though your question sums up to: "I need A, B, C. Show me how to do it".

Comment: @vishalkumar I am here all day, I don't leave. I will help you. You need to be more exact in your question, ask about one thing, show us what you have tried, and why it isn't doing what you think it should. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi All,I had solve my issue.. that for all effort by all.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
choice = str(input("Press 1 to Insert 2 to Delete 3 to exit "))
if choice == '1':
    avp_code = raw_input("enter avp code: ")
    avp_name = raw_input("enter avp name: ")
    avp_type = raw_input("enter the avp type: ")
    vendor_id = raw_input("enter the vendor Id: ")
    line1 = '\t\t<AVP code="'+avp_code+'" name="'+avp_name+'" vendor-id="'+vendor_id+'">\n\t\t\t<type>\n\t\t\t\t<'+avp_type+'/>\n\t\t\t</type>'
    line2 = ''
    while avp_type == "enum":
        enum_type = raw_input("enter enumeration name: ")
        line2 += '\n\t\t\t<enum name="'+enum_type+'"/>'
        enum_choice = raw_input("Add another enumeration name: yes Or no: ")
        if enum_choice == "yes":
            continue
        else:
            break
    line3 = '\n\t\t</AVP>'
    lines = line1 + line2 + line3
    for line in fileinput.input(GMPS_TOP + "_hss1/dra/test.xml", inplace=True):
        if line.strip() == '</Base>':
            print lines
        print line,
if choice == 3:
    break
```

enjoy!!!